# user-defined literals and whitespace and c++11 issues

Tags: qt, c++11, gcc

I'm compiling very simple code and as output I receive error:

```
`../untitled6/main.cpp:17:1: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator"" __FILE__'
     connect(&d_t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doPlay()));`
```

The code is following:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    void Play()
    {
         connect(&d_t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(doPlay()));
    }

public slots:
    void doPlay() {}

private:
    QTimer d_t;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Test test;
    test.Play();
    return a.exec();
}
```

It is happened only if I include c++11 support in my project. Without this support the compilation is Okey. I have read about user-defined literals and whitespace for gcc ver. 4.7 when c++11 support is included. But my code doesn't include any  **FILE** code.... I found that problem is related to SIGNAL and SLOT constructions. But I have no idea what is wrong here...
P.S. For compilation I use sh4-linux-g++ (GCC) 4.8.

I have found that this issue don't observed for release build configuration. It seems it is issue for debug build configuration...

Comment: SIGNAL and SLOT (from Qt) are macros which obviously expand to incorrect code here. You should try to analyze the resulting code (use `gcc -E` and have a look at that line).

Comment: What commands are you using to compile the code? As the file contains the Q_OBJECT macro, do you use "moc" (https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Qt 4.8.1:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22847

You should upgrade.